# Existence of an antiderivative function on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

**Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be  continuous at $x$ for every $x\in I$  where $I\subset \mathbb R$ could be arbitrary. Does there always exist a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $I$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in I$?**

The definition of a primitive is naturally defined on an interval. what sort of weaker result can we obtain under weaker hypotheses?.

- If I is an interval or an open set, the answer to the question is
  positive.
- If f is locally Lebesgue integrable,the answer to the question is
  also positive.

I have already asked the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855483/existence-of-an-antiderivative-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbbr

Comment: It's also yes if $I$ is closed, because then there exists a continuous $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $g|_I=f|_I$.

Comment: Do you mean differentiable on I = for a given open interval U covering I, f is differentiable on $I \cap U$ and possibly more points? Because otherwise, a lot of the exotic sets you can think of have no differentiable structure.

Comment: My first guess would be to: (1) replace $f$ by $g(x) = \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)$; we have $f = g$ on $I$, and $g$ is lower semi-continuous, and therefore measurable; (2) note that there is an open set $U$ containing $I$ such that $g$ is locally bounded on $U$; (3) define $F$ to be the indefinite Lebesgue integral of $g$ on $U$, and whatever function in the complement of $U$.

Comment: @Marcus Aurelius I suppose only that f and F are defined on $\mathbb{R}$  or an open set $D \supset I$ and F differentiable at every  $x\in I$

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki for (1), I'am  agree with you. I do not see for the moment (2)

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki  Upper or lower semicontinuity is not a sufficient condition for a function to be locally bounded. Let
$f(x) = \ln |x|$, if $x \neq  0$, and 0, if $x = 0.$
Then f is upper semicontinuous, but it is not locally bounded at 0

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich  thank you for your comment, I see now the reason page 4 https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Rudin/Rudin_4.pdf

Comment: @Tina: For each $x \in I$ there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $g$ is bounded in $U_x = (x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$. Define $U$ to be the union of $U_x$ over $x \in I$. Then $g$ is locally bounded on $U$.

Comment: Ok, I see. and for (3)  Any locally bounded measurable function is locally Lebesgue-integrable. You can make your solution.

Comment: @Tina: I think it is not much different from Pietro Majer's answer; I'd rather accept his answer then.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki I will accept it also after having understood it,  she is very "rich", but your proposition of solution is very different because it avoids us the concept of Darboux integral and especially the second part of its reasoning;  since,  your proposition of solution, it us forurnie a measurable function locally bounded  which coincides with f on I, What do you think?

Comment: @Tina: Done. (Riemann/Darboux integral is far more elementary than the Lebesgue one, though).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's start with the case of a locally bounded function $f:J\to\mathbb{R}$ (say defined on some nonempty open interval $ J\subset\mathbb{R}$, with a fixed $x_0\in J$). We may consider for any $x\in J$  the  [upper Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_integrals) of $f$ from $x_0\in J$ to $x$: $$F(x):=\overline  {\int^x_{x_0}}f(t)dt$$ 
(with the usual convention that  $\overline  {\int_b^a}f:=-\overline  {\int_a^b}f$ for $a\le b$). The upper integral is not linear wrto functions, but it is additive on intervals: $\overline  {\int_a^b}f=\overline  {\int_a^c}f+\overline  {\int_c^b}f$ for  $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, recall that for $a\le b$
$$(b-a)\inf_{a\le t\le b}f(t)\le\underline  {\int_a^b}fdt\le\overline  {\int_a^b}fdt\le (b-a)\sup_{a\le t\le b}f(t).$$
As a consequence, the fundamental theorem of calculus still holds true for $F$ at any point $x$ of continuity of $f$:

$$F(x+h)=F(x)+ f(x)h+o(h),\qquad h\to0$$

so $F:J\to\mathbb{R}$ fulfills the requirement in the case of locally bounded $f$.

For a general $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, I would suggest the following argument to reduce to the preceding case. Since $f$ is locally bounded at any point of continuity, the set of continuity points is covered by a collection of disjoint open intervals $J_k$  such that $f_{|J_k}:J_k\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally bounded. By the preceding argument we have a collection of $F_k:J_k\to\mathbb{R}$ that we can glue to a single $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  such that $F'(x)=F_k'(x)=f(x)$ at any continuity point $x\in J_k$ of $f$, and e.g. $F(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\cup_k J_k$.

Comment: I guess you can handle non-measurable functions here? Otherwise, the OP already pointed out the more general fact that $f\in L^1_{loc}$ is sufficient (which is obvious, by defining $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$).

Comment: They are the connected components of the open set N on which f is locally bounded; N is a nbd of the set cont(f)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I was concerned about $f$ not being bounded on such a component, but that doesn't seem to be a problem in your argument.

Comment: Upper integral. Not linear but additive on intervals. Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for...

Comment: I feel like I'd like to "publish" a majorly detailed version of this on MSE for the benefit of the kids over there. With attribution, of course. That would be ok with you? Heh, for the sake of appearances I'd include a request that any upvotes be sent here...

Comment: @ChristianRemling That bothered me too. If we say $f$ is locally bounded on $S$ if for every $x$ there exists $\delta$ with $f$ bounded on $(x-\delta,x+delta)$ then it's clear that if $f$ is locally bounded on $S_\alpha$ (open) for every $\alpha$ then $f$ is locally bounded on $\cup_\alpha S_\alpha$. So $f$ is locally bounded on those components. And locally bounded implies bounded on compact sets, which is enough for the rest of the argument

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Of course, this would be nice

Comment: @ Pietro Maje Thank you very much, I am studying your solution (for the moment, I did not understand all the details).

Comment: @Tina feel free to ask for details.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer Thank you, it's very kind of you

Comment: @Tina I'm planning on posting a more detailed version on MSE...

Comment: @  David C. Ullrich  Good idea.  Thank you for your interest ,  your help and your support. If the question was rejected on MSE, I would not have the courage to ask it here.

Answer (score 4):

As requested, I turn my comments into an answer.

---

First of all, we replace $f$ by its lower semi-continuous envelope:
$$ g(x) = \liminf_{y \to x} f(x) . $$
Observe that $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in I$ and $g$ is continuous at every $x \in I$. Furthermore, $g$ is lower semi-continuous, and hence Borel measurable.

If $g$ is continuous at $x$, then there is a neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $g$ is bounded in $U_x$. Let $U$ be the union of $U_x$ over all $x \in I$.

Consider a connected component $(a, b)$ of $U$. Then $g$ is locally bounded on $(a, b)$ (for any compact subinterval of $(a, b)$ can be covered by finitely many sets $U_x$ with $x \in I$), and thus we can define
$$ F(x) = \int_{(a+b)/2}^x g(y) dy $$
for $x \in (a, b)$. Clearly, $F$ is differentiable at every point of continuity $x \in (a, b)$ of $g$, and $F'(x) = g(x)$. In particular, $F'(x) = g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in I \cap (a, b)$.

We define $F$ as above on every connected component $(a, b)$ of $U$, and we set $F(x) = 0$ for $x \notin U$. By construction, $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in I \cap U = I$, as desired.